# Access2010: Opening screen to display animation while linking tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

When my Access 2010 application loads, I need to link to a couple Oracle tables for security reasons before I show a logon screen.  I would like to show an animated gif if possible while the tables are being linked in the background. 
I have created a form that has the animated gif as a WebBrowser control. When the screen opens, the animated gif works great.
So I thought I would open a form and call the animated gif form then
Me.Repaint
DoEvents

and then my subroutine to LinkTables, after which I wish to close both forms.

The animated gif form opens, shows a frozen image, links and then closes.

Is there anyway to actually show an animation while something is occuring in the background?

Comment: Might give this a look: http://www.databison.com/simulating-multithreading-in-vba-using-excel/

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading in Access simply isn't possible but you can do something similiar:

1. Split your animated gif into a series of still images that can be viewed sequentially: A,B,C, etc.
2. Split your background process into a series of tasks: 1,2,3 etc.
3. Make your loading form.  Show image A.
4. When your background process finishes task 1, replace image A with B.
5. When your background process finishes task 2, replace image B with C.
6. repeat.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes - sure does.  thanks. perhaps in Access 2018 we'll get multi-threading.